# How do I get rid of the looping error messages from this script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

PREAMBLE='\usepackage{fontspec}\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}\usepackage{xeCJK}\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}\pagestyle{empty}'

for f in "$@"; do
    if [[ -s "$f" ]]; then
        pygmentize -f tex -O "style=$STYLE,linenos,full,preamble=$PREAMBLE" $f \
            | xelatex -jobname=$(basename $f) -output-directory=$SCRATCH
    else
        echo $ERR "Error: File <$f> not found." && exit 1
    fi

    [[ "$STYLE" = "default" ]] \
        && pdfcrop $SCRATCH/$(basename $f.pdf) $(basename $f | tr . -).pdf \
        || pdfcrop $SCRATCH/$(basename $f.pdf) $(basename $f | tr . -)-$STYLE.pdf
    
    (( ALL == 1 )) \
        && { pygmentize -f tex -O "style=bw,linenos,full,preamble=$PREAMBLE" $f \
                 | xelatex -jobname=$(basename $f) -output-directory=$SCRATCH; \
             pdfcrop $SCRATCH/$(basename $f.pdf) $(basename $f | tr . -)-bw.pdf; }
done
```

Comment: Which part or your script that produces that error? `pygmentize` ? `xelatex` ? or something else

Comment: What are the error messages?

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues. First, you seem to be trying to compile a malformed LaTeX file. These are LaTeX errors, nothing to do with the script itself:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `\def {\char `\\}.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: ! Argument of \@firstofone has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.105 \AtBeginDocument
                                 { \xeCJK@document@hook } 
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.105 \AtBeginDocument
                                 { \xeCJK@document@hook }
```

To figure those out, you will need to examine your LaTeX code. You might want to try posting the code on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ and asking there.

---

The only shell error you get is that you seem to be missing a command:

```
./src2pdf.sh: line 65: pdfcrop: command not found
```

You are trying to run a command called `pdfcrop` but that doesn't exist on your system. I don't know what operating system you are running, so I don't know how you can find it, but that's what you need to sort out. On Ubuntu, [that tool is part of the `texlive-extra-utils` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&section=all&arch=any&keywords=pdfcrop&searchon=contents), so if you are running Ubuntu, you can try:

```
sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils
```

On Arch, you can find it on AUR as part of `pdfcropmargins`, so try (replace `trizen` with your preferred AUR manager):

```
trizen -S pdfcropmargins
```

Comment: @AaronWalker the remaining errors are all LaTeX stuff. Looks like you're missing a font. I can't really help any more, [tex.se] seems like a better bet.